# Why is my home page nav showing up different than subpages?

Tags: css, hover, nav

The kerning between letters is off on homepage vs the subpages. I have no idea why as they all use the same code in the nav links in html and css. I've attached some css and html below, I'm not sure what's going on with the homepage only, like I said all the subpages have the same code here.

[homepage nav](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WsQwf.png)

[subpage nav](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pkPK2.png)

```
    <header>
         <div class="container"> 
        <nav class="navbar">
          <div class="logo"><img src="logo/logo_white.svg" alt="vic logo"/>
                  </div>
            <ul class="nav_links">
                <li class="active"> 
                    <a href="index.html" class="nav_link">home</a>
                    <li>
                     <a href="stills.html" class="nav_link">stills</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                       <a href="designs.html" class="nav_link">designs</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                </nav>
                 </header>
    
    
    .header {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        align-items: center;
        color: #f8f8f8;
    }
    
    .navbar {
        display: flex;
        width: 90%;
        justify-content: space-between;
        align-items: center;
        padding-top: 4px;
        padding-bottom: 4px;
        font-size: 18px;
     
    }
    
    .logo {
        width: 140px;
        display: inline-block;
        padding-left: 48px;
        max-width: 140px;
        transition: transform .7s ease-in-out;
    
    }
    
    
    .logo:hover{
        transform: scale(1.4) rotate(10deg);
        color: #f8f8f8;
    }
    
    
    .nav_links li {
        margin-left: 24px;
    }
    
    .nav_links:hover {
       color:#91e9d6;
       text-decoration: underline;
       font-weight: 600;
    }
    
    .nav_links, ul {
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        display: flex;
    }
    
    .nav_link li {
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 0px 20px;
    }
    
    
    .nav_link li, a {
        display: inline;
        float: left;
        font-size: 24px;
        font-family: "neue-haas-grotesk-display", sans-serif;
        margin-left: 16px;
        margin-top: 24px;
        margin-bottom: 36px;
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #f8f8f8;
    }
    
    /* hover link*/
    li, a:hover {
        color: #91e9d6;
        text-decoration: underline;
        font-weight: 600;
    }
    
    /* selected link */
    li, a:active {
        color: orange;
    }
```

Comment: Are you referencing the CSS file correctly in your subpages? Make sure the path is correct first.

Comment: DOH! Thank you. I know what it is! I have an Adobe font I linked and I didn't add it to other pages.